# How to change weight of a button programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a CountDownTimer that is activated by a "Set" button and then can be stopped by a "Cancel" button.

When the activity starts, I want only the set button to show. When the countdown is started, I want to hide the "Set" button and show the "Cancel" button.

I want to do this by changing the weight of the button. How do I do this? I have found similar questions that have answers that don't work when I try them. I think those answers are just fragments of the full code, which is what I'm looking for.

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonsContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setDelay"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="activateDelay"
            android:text="Set Delay" />
       <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelDelay"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="cancelDelay"
            android:text="Cancel Delay" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I know I'm using hard-coded strings, they're just for development purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use the weight property to hide a button? `layout_weight` is used to share space proportionately (according to the weights given). I guess you *could* "hide" a button by setting the `layout_weight` to 0 (and the weight on the other to something greater than 0). I've never updated the layout parameters *after* adding the views to viewgroup, but `parent.updateViewLayout(childView, updatedParams)` looks promising.

In any case, use `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the button you want gone; it is hidden and the rest of the Views are laid out as though the button is not present. (You can use `View.INVISIBLE` to hide the View, but the rest of the Views are laid out as though the button is there - you just can't see it.)

Here's an untested "fragment" ;P

```
private Button set;
private Button cancel;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // it's typical to use underscore notation for IDs - R.id.set_delay
    set = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setDelay);
    cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelDelay);
}

public void activateDelay(View button) {
    set.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void cancelDelay(View button) {
    set.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cancel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

And in your XML, you'd start with the "Set" button visible (by default), and "Cancel" gone, both with `match_parent` for width:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonsContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setDelay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:onClick="activateDelay"
        android:text="Set Delay" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelDelay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="cancelDelay"
        android:text="Cancel Delay" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note, if you have a reason (even if it's crazy :P) for wanting to use weight, I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: I wanted to use weight because with an object that has a weight of 0 and another with a weight of 1 in a linear layout, the 1 will fill the linear layout and the 0 will not show at all. I'm new to android, and it was just a method that seemed do-able for me.

Comment: @TiberiumFusion fair enough, very reasonable, and I commend the fact that you had a decent idea in your mind, though in future, it'd be helpful (to you and the answerers) if you explained this reasoning in the question; it shows you've thought about the problem, and also will help others see if the constraint is not required (as was the case here). welcome to SO :)